# How to call model class method from controller in megento?

Tags: magento, model, controller, call

I have created a new model class in checkout/type name Cartpage.php and it has a method name `addValue($id)`. Want to call this model class method from `saveShippingMethodAction()` in  OnepageController.php at Checkout/controllers. I have called in several ways but it gives me an error:

> Fatal error:  Call to a member function addValue() on a non-object in .../app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php

**I have tried:**

```
$myModel = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cartpage');
$return = $myModel->addValue($my_value);
```

**Model:**

```
class Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Cartpage extends  Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract
{
        public function addValue($value)
    {
    return $value;
    }

}
```

How can I call my custom model from OnepageController?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your module is located under `Checkout/Model/Type/Cartpage.php` the correct `classgroup`to call is `checkout/type_cartpage`
so use `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_cartpage');` instead of `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cartpage');`

However it looks like you are adding your model class under the `core` namespace which is a nogo in magento.

create you own module und the `local` namespace and create `rewrites` for the parts you want/need to change